# TFS Build giving different results according to build requestor

Tags: selenium, tfs, build

We have a TFS (2013) build defined which runs a project of Selenium tests against the web site in the solution (chromedriver).  If run locally, by any developer, three of the tests currently fail.  The build agent is on a separate box from the tfs build controller and running under a local admin account.

With the code all checked in, if the build is manually triggered by three of the developers, it works as expected - three tests fail.  However, if the build is launched by either of the other two developers, almost all of the tests fail, either with a...

```
System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

or

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
```

...type of error.

All developers have the same rights in TFS. Can anyone suggest how the id of the requesting user should be able to influence the results of a build being run remotely and under different credentials?  (Any solutions would also be appreciated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that this is as a result of screwed up AD Groups on the network.

Since the originating user's credentials are actually carried over to the build process, rather that the local admin credentials being used, we (eventually) discovered some different AD memberships of groups between the developers which impacted the permissions on some folders on the build box, stopping certain resources from being accessed.

Unfortunately the errors raised by Selenium were complete red herrings and hiding the actual cause - difficult to diagnose until we actually ran the builds locally on the build server under the various developers' credentials.

Comment: You should have seen permission errors in the event log of the build server.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Ironically the build user did not appear to have permissions to write to the event log either, or so I presume from the lack of entries there.